# What is a better way to handle a RuntimeException in a method?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I've heard that it's not always a good practice to handle runtime exceptions. I've implemented a method that takes a product rating as an argument and if the current product object has this rating, it returns a ProductDTO object. The only way I found to make the method work as expected is with the use of a Runtime exception. But according to Joshua Bloch it is a very bad idea to use exceptions for control flow.

Is there a way to improve the logic of the method?

```
public ProductDTO findByRating(int productRating) {
    ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
    if (productRating == this.avgRating()) {
        productDTO.setProductName(productName);
        productDTO.setProductsLeftForSale(productsLeftForSale());
        productDTO.setAvgRating(avgRating());
        productDTO.setTotalVotes(reviews.size());
        return productDTO;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("No Product found with the rating: %s", productRating));
    }
}
```

.

```
List<ProductDTO> productDTOList = new ArrayList<>();    
        int rating = 5;
        for (BaseProduct product : products) {
            try {
                ProductDTO productDTO = product.findByRating(rating);
                if (productDTO != null) {
                    productDTOList.add(productDTO);
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with returning `null`?

Comment: If you're going to throw an exception, throw a `NoSuchElementException`, rather than a more general `RuntimeException`.

Comment: You could return an `Optional<ProductDTO>`.

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino if I do so `productDTOList` contains `null` values as well.

Comment: @samba but you already have `productDTO != null` check....

Comment: @samba you test for null in the calling method, so no, `productDTOList` will not contain null values.

Comment: So is it a better startegy not to throw `RuntimeException` or `NoSuchElementException` and make `findByRating` method return `null` instead?

Comment: `null` is a horrible thing to have... avoid it at all cost... `Option` is a much better way.

Comment: before you guys proposing others using `null`, make sure you read the apologies from Tony Hoare. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it looks a little better:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

...

public Optional<ProductDTO> findByRating(int rating) {
    return this.avgRating() == rating ? Optional.of(createDTO()) : Optional.empty();
}

private ProductDTO createDTO() {
    ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDTO();
    productDTO.setProductName(productName);
    productDTO.setProductsLeftForSale(productsLeftForSale());
    productDTO.setAvgRating(avgRating());
    productDTO.setTotalVotes(reviews.size());
    return productDTO;
}

public List<ProductDTO> findProductsByRating(int rating) {
    return products.stream()
            .map(product -> product.findByRating(rating))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanation. What if I want to throw a runtime exception like.. `orElseThrow(() -> new MyException(someArgument))` if the non-existing rating value is entered. How can it be used properly in this example?

Comment: I think it is a bad practice to throw an Exception in this case. It is a normal situation in your program if a Product has another rating. Usually you should throw an Exception if anything goes wrong: for instance you call `getById(long id)` and you cannot find a Product with such id.

Comment: You could also first filter our product list  
`products.stream().filter(p -> p.getRating() == rating)` after which you map the product to your DTO object. After that you use `findFirst()` which returns an Optional.